# Can I combine an executable with another executable (Windows Service Program) and run this program as a logical service?

Tags: python, c++, windows

> Can I combine an executable with another executable (Windows Service Program) and run this program as a logical service?

By *combining*, I mean to form a single executable.

I want to write a Windows Service, and I've followed some tutorials that show how to do it using C++, i.e. writing the Service Program (in Windows) and using `ServiceMain()` functions as logical services.

However, I prefer not to write the `ServiceMain()` functions in C++. Instead, I wonder whether I could write these logical services using Python and compile to binary using py2exe.

Is this possible? - could I substitute the `ServiceMain()` functions for py2exe compiled modules? If so, please provide the details on how to do it.

Comment: Please clarify the merge operation of two executables.  Are you merging assembly language instructions?  Are you combining all the functions (union)?  Are you appending one executable to another?  Is one executable supposed to run after the other?  Are you talking about hooking (chaining) executables?  Merging brings up pictures of examples that won't work correctly.

Comment: I've updated the question. By merging I mean to create a single executable out of several programs.

Comment: How does the OS know when and where the additional executables are?  Is the first executable to run the second executable after finishing?

Comment: I recommend searching the internet for "windows appending executables".  Also read up on "ELF file format".  You may also want to post to SuperUser@stackexchange.com to find out if Windows can execute program X in a file containing N programs.

Comment: Hmm, I know you can execute one program from another in Windows using e.g. the CreateProcess() function, right?

This require two seperate executables on the disk. 

Is it possible to somehow "merge" these programs toghether (into a single program) , such that the same behavior can be achieved using just a single executable?

Answer (score 0):

You could have your python executable call the c++ executable and have the executable take in command line arguments.  So basically in python have the service main code and a few basic cases that will call into a normal c++ executable.  Not extremely efficient, but it works